# Add a view at the end of a uitextview in swift or obj-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiscrollview

My question is very simple. I have a Uitextview on the full screen with more text than there is space. Now i want to display a view at the end of the uitextview when the user scrolls to the end. It should appear as one scrollview.

I tried:

- adding the button on top of the textview (overlaps the text)
- creating a uiscrollview with a textview on top and then:

Code:

```
scrollView?.contentSize.height = textView!.contentSize.height
```

But then i dont get the results i want. The textview behaves as a scrollview and the scrollview as another scrollview. If i scroll the scrollview in the delegate of the textview it wont help because the textviews size is not as big as the scrollviews contentSize.

Any Ideas on how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: You can create a label in scrollview and add another view below it.

Comment: I solved my problem already. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was really easy. If anyone is interested:

Just add the view on top of the uitextview and then expand the contentsize of the textview depending on the view height. Problem solved.

Comment: You should add some code to fully answer your question.